# Laravel Change Path Context

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.7

I have Laravel(5.7) project and will be deployed to a server (nginx) with multiple projects. I am running the project in my Local machine using Apache and I tried to run it with subdirectory and it is working in my machine.

We have a problem in deployment of my project in subdirectory of the server (nginx), I don't know if the Laravel project has the problem because everytime we go to the http://172.1.1.1/sample of my project it always show the "404 Page not found" of Laravel because Laravel thought that /sample is a path so I think 172.1.1.1/sample runs the Laravel but it didn't make /sample as it's root but when we go to 172.1.1.1 the other project running here is working. What I already did is add the following code in my Laravel project.

In my AppServiceProvider.php - I add the following code:

```
public function boot()
{

       \URL::forceRootUrl(\Config::get('app.url'));   

        if (str_contains(\Config::get('app.url'), 'https://')) {
            \URL::forceScheme('https');
            //use \URL:forceSchema('https') if you use laravel < 5.4
        }
    }
```

So that when I change the APP_URL in .env of my project, it will work.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:9021/sample
```

And add the following in the .htaccess of my public folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sample/
```

So it is working for my local machine but this doesn't work when we tried to deploy this. Once we go to 172.1.1.1/sample (sample-ip) it will just show the "404 Page not found".

What I want to know is if there are other way to change the context path of laravel 5.7. Because I am not the one who configure the nginx in the server but I want to make sure that the problem is not because of Laravel 5.7.

Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: this problem can be solved using virtual host

Comment: How this can be solve sir @ShaielndraGupta? I mean is my configs in Laravel correct or do I need to change something in Laravel? I just want to make sure that the configs for Laravel is okay because I am not the one who handle nginx configs. Thank you sir.

Comment: do want `http://localhost:9021/sample` as your base path as you can run multiple project in single machine..??

Comment: There are more than 1 projects in the server. So project 1 is running in http://localhost:9021 then we will deploy my project in http://localhost:9021/sample. So the root folder of my Laravel project will be http://localhost:9021/sample. But what happened is Laravel considered /sample as a route path so it returns a "404 Page not found".

Comment: Configure your nginx to use localhost:9022 for your project instead. `APP_URL` must contain only the domain name such as `APP_URL=localhost:9022`

Comment: @Mysteryos then how can we make the Laravel read localhost:9022/sample as its root domain. So that it won't read /sample as its own route.

Answer (score 0):

see this documentation

[laravel with nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: But what if the project is in the subdirectory. Then in nginx.conf we will just add ```location /sample {}``` right? Do I need to configure something in Laravel also?

Comment: now it's not laravel's way of working you have to separate your project and make a configuration file that points to that project's public folder

Comment: What do you mean? Our configuration points to the public of the laravel folder. So we have this ```location /sample {}``` - when we access http://location:9022/sample the laravel reads it as laravel route not the laravel root.

Comment: Should I put all the public files to /sample folder? then the rest of laravel files - I will create "laravel" folder so I will now have
<root_folder>
      - <laravel_folder>  (the rest of laravel files)
      - <sample_folder> (all public files)

Then I will just edit the index.php in public files and point it to laravel folder?